# How to check whether a date sting has a particular format

Tags: java, string

I have a web service in which we pass a date as 
string ::

- `fromDate=2012-11-06 22:16:23.157&toDate=2012-11-06
  22:44:56.367`(**THIS IS TYPE 1**)

and

- `fromDate=2012-11-06&toDate=2012-11-07`(**THIS IS TYPE 2**)

NOW, what i want is when we have "TYPE 1", then -

```
List<something> myList=vc.getsomething(FromDate,ToDate);
else{
   String newFromDate = fromDate + " " + constant.ZERO_APPEND;
   String newToDate = toDate + " " + constant.ZERO_APPEND;
   List<something> myList=vc.getsomething(newFromDate,newToDate);
}
```

how to do this..?? please help..

Comment: You should try to make your question more precise. It's impossible to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check the format, you should use regular expressions in java and check the format using `str.matches("Regex here")` ([regex in java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html))

or if your format is kind of fixed, you can just check with `str.contains(":")` to check for first format

Comment: as you can see that in both string dates, we have ":"..

Comment: I do not see where in 2nd format you have ":"

Comment: ok..sry.. if we have date as 2012-11-06, then we append 00:00:00 to date..

Comment: I dont understand your question ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` when comparing strings. Here's an example:

```
String first = "text";
String second = "text";

if(first.equals(second))
{
    System.out.println("Strings are equal!");
}
```

Comment: but both dates have different format , then how to compare??

Comment: @Deep_89: You'd need to parse the strings. If the strings to be parsed are consistent, which your date strings appear to be, then it's relatively simple. If you want to do something more complex, look into [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you want something like this? But I might need a little bit more context as I do not fully understand the question.

```
if(FromDate.contains(":")){ //If it contains : from the seconds separator
    List<something> myList=vc.getsomething(FromDate,ToDate);
}
else{
   String newFromDate = fromDate + " " + constant.ZERO_APPEND;
   String newToDate = toDate + " " + constant.ZERO_APPEND;
   List<something> myList=vc.getsomething(newFromDate,newToDate);
}
```

Comment: both dates have ":", when we have date of TYPE-1, then call list, other wise if we have TYPE-2, then append 00:00:00 with date of TYPE-2.. then we call list again with modified date.. how to achive this ??

Comment: @Deep_89 I don't understand what you want. In your example Type1 does not have ':' when passed to your webservice.